# What is the right way to allocate data to pass to an FFI call?

Tags: rust, ffi

After [discussing/learning about the correct way to call a FFI of the Windows-API from Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534712/should-i-pass-a-mutable-reference-or-transfer-ownership-of-a-variable-in-the-con), I played with it a little bit further and would like to double-check my understanding.

I have a Windows API that is called twice. In the first call, it returns the size of the buffer that it will need for its actual out parameter. Then, it is called a second time with a buffer of sufficient size. I'm currently using a `Vec` as a datatype for this buffer (see example below).

The code works but I'm wondering whether this is right way to do it or whether it would be better to utilize a function like `alloc::heap::allocate` to directly reserve some memory and then to use  `transmute` to convert the result from the FFI back. Again, my code works but I'm trying to look a little bit behind the scenes.

```
extern crate advapi32;
extern crate winapi;
extern crate widestring;
use widestring::WideCString;
use std::io::Error as IOError;
use winapi::winnt;

fn main() {
    let mut lp_buffer: Vec<winnt::WCHAR> = Vec::new();
    let mut pcb_buffer: winapi::DWORD = 0;

    let rtrn_bool = unsafe {
        advapi32::GetUserNameW(lp_buffer.as_mut_ptr(),
                               &mut pcb_buffer )
    };

    if rtrn_bool == 0 {

        match IOError::last_os_error().raw_os_error() {
            Some(122) => {
                // Resizing the buffers sizes so that the data fits in after 2nd 
                lp_buffer.resize(pcb_buffer as usize, 0 as winnt::WCHAR);
            } // This error is to be expected
            Some(e) => panic!("Unknown OS error {}", e),
            None => panic!("That should not happen"),
        }
    }


    let rtrn_bool2 = unsafe {
        advapi32::GetUserNameW(lp_buffer.as_mut_ptr(), 
                               &mut pcb_buffer )
    };

    if rtrn_bool2 == 0 {
        match IOError::last_os_error().raw_os_error() {
            Some(e) => panic!("Unknown OS error {}", e),
            None => panic!("That should not happen"),
        }
    }

    let widestr: WideCString = unsafe { WideCString::from_ptr_str(lp_buffer.as_ptr()) };

    println!("The owner of the file is {:?}", widestr.to_string_lossy());
}
```

Dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
advapi32-sys = "0.2"
winapi = "0.2"
widestring = "*"
```

Comment: Tangentially related: [Allocating an object for C / FFI library calls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28154683/155423).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you would use [`std::alloc::alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/fn.alloc.html) because you can then specify the desired alignment as part of the *layout*:

```
pub unsafe fn alloc(layout: Layout) -> *mut u8
```

The main downside is that you need to *know the alignment*, even when you free the allocation.

It's common practice to use a `Vec` as an easy allocation mechanism, but you need to be careful when using it as such.

1. Make sure that your units are correct — is the "length" parameter the number of *items* or the number of *bytes*?
2. If you dissolve the `Vec` into component parts, you need to

   1. track the *length* and the *capacity*. Some people use [`shrink_to_fit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.shrink_to_fit) to ensure those two values are the same.
   2. Avoid *crossing the streams* - that memory was allocated by Rust and **must** be freed by Rust. Convert it back into a `Vec` to be dropped.
3. Beware that an empty `Vec` does **not** have a NULL pointer!:

   ```
   fn main() {
       let v: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
       println!("{:p}", v.as_ptr());
       // => 0x1
   }
   ```

---

For your specific case, I might suggest using the `capacity` of the `Vec` instead of tracking the second variable yourself. You'll note that you forgot to update `pcb_buffer` after the first call, so I'm pretty sure that the code will always fail. It's annoying because it needs to be a mutable reference so you can't completely get away from it.

Additionally, instead of `extend`ing the `Vec`, you could just [`reserve`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.reserve) space.

There's also no guarantee that the size required during the first call will be the same as the size required during the second call. You *could* do some kind of loop, but then you have to worry about an infinite loop happening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, I guess I'll better stick with with the stable solution of a Vec. I'll change the content of the Vec to winnt::CHAR so that there is not difference between the number of items and the length. I guess that this will make it easier.

Comment: I have two questions regarding your answer though:
- What do you exactly mean by saying that I have to convert the memory back into a Vec to be dropped.
- I'm not sure that I could use the capacity instead of my second variable as this variable is also passed to the FFI as an output parameter. The Windows API will overwrite the content of this variable and I guess that it will not be a good idea to do this with the capacity of my Vec. Or did I misunderstand you in this aspect?

Comment: @Norbert I clarified a smidge. Converting back to a `Vec` is only if you've decomposed a `Vec` to start with; your case doesn't seem to have that. For the latter, I meant to use the value of `capacity` instead of `0`, but you do have to have another variable around to pass as the reference.