# Calling winapi with OsString and converting back to String

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm struggling with calling the wide-char version of `GetUserName`. The UTF-8 call works, though there might be a better way to do this:

```
#[cfg(windows)] extern crate advapi32;
#[cfg(windows)] extern crate winapi;

use std::ffi::CString;

fn get_user_name() -> String {
    let mut sz: u32 = 64;
    unsafe {
        let mut username = CString::from_vec_unchecked(vec![0; sz as usize]);
        let ptr = username.into_raw();
        advapi32::GetUserNameA(ptr as *mut i8, &mut sz as *mut u32);
        CString::from_raw(ptr).to_str().unwrap().to_owned()
    }
}
```

Then I tried the UTF-16 version. This works but looks wrong as I have to create this blank string for `OsStr::new()`:

```
fn get_user_name() -> String {
    // for windows
    use std::ffi::OsStr;
    let mut sz: u32 = 64;
    let mut username = OsStr::new("                            ")
        .encode_wide()
        .collect::<Vec<u16>>();
    unsafe {
        advapi32::GetUserNameW(username.as_mut_ptr() as *mut u16, &mut sz as *mut u32);
    }
    String::from_utf16(&username[..sz as usize]).unwrap()
}
```

I also tried using `OsString::with_capacity()`, but this crashes:

```
fn get_user_name() -> String {
    // for windows
    use std::ffi::OsStr;
    let mut sz: u32 = 64;
    let mut username = OsString::with_capacity(sz as usize)
        .as_os_str()
        .encode_wide()
        .collect::<Vec<u16>>();
    unsafe {
        advapi32::GetUserNameW(username.as_mut_ptr() as *mut u16, &mut sz as *mut u32);
    }
    String::from_utf16(&username[..sz as usize]).unwrap()
}
```

There are other answers on Stack Overflow where Rust creates a string to pass into a function (e.g. `MessageBoxW`), but none where the size is determined by Windows and Rust has to allocate space to be populated later.

What is the correct way of calling a wide char function on Windows where Rust has to preallocate a buffer and then convert back (eventually) to a standard UTF-8 string?

Comment: I'd pass the buffers directly from `Vec<i8>` / `Vec<u16>` allocations (or arrays on the stack...); convert them to strings **after** they were filled.

Comment: @Ronnie Please post the answer as a proper answer, thanks.

Comment: **You** asked [Calling the GetUserName WinAPI function with a mutable string doesn't populate the string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44709780/155423), thus one would expect you to remember the answer.

Comment: @Shepmaster For some reason didn't appear in the search. Please delete this question if you wish. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From comments, using a `Vec` directly is the simplest approach.

```
fn get_user_name() -> String {
    // for windows
    let mut sz: u32 = 64;
    let mut username: Vec<u16> = vec![0; sz as usize];
    unsafe {
        advapi32::GetUserNameW(username.as_mut_ptr() as *mut u16, &mut sz as *mut u32);
    }
    String::from_utf16(&username[..sz as usize]).unwrap()
}
```

Comment: This code fails to check the return value of `GetUserNameW` and thus is terribly unsafe.